# Como selecionar um checkbox e recuperar dados no banco de dados?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

Tenho 2 tipos de `checkbox` e preciso que ao selecionar um dos dois seja exibido um campo do tipo `input text` com as informações vinda do banco de dados. O campo `input` será desabilitado, ou seja, será somente para exibição.

Alguém tem algum modelo para me basear?
Ou alguma ideia de como realizar isso?

Comment: Me parece ampla essa pergunta, não entendi se o problema é para recuperar os dados do BD ou como realizar a requisição quando o `checkbox` for selecionado. Você fez algo? Se sim, inclua o código junto a pergunta e mostre onde tem dúvidas.

Answer (score 2):

Sua pergunta é muito genérica, mesmo assim da para fornecer o exemplo que você quer

Você precisa das seguintes etapas para realizar esse objetivo !

1. Criar um monitoramento  com javascript para detectar quando o
   checkbox foi ativo ou desativado
2. Acessar seu banco de dados, sem que a pagina carregue
3. Retornar um texto do banco de dados e incluir um input disabled na
   tela

Então, vamos monitorar o elemento checkbox usando Jquery, vamos acessar uma camada que tenha acesso ao banco usando ajax, e vamos usar append para incluir isso na tela, veja o exemplo !

Pagina.html

```
    // Monitorando um checkbox com jquery
    $(".checkbox").change(function() {
        // verifica se ele está no estado checked
        if(this.checked) {
            // usando ajax para acessar o servidor
            $.ajax({
                // Passe alguma coisa via get se necessario
                url: "resposta.php?param="+this.value,
                cache: false
            })
                    // buscando o resultado
                    .done(function( texto ) {
                        //usando append para incluir o input no
                        $( "#id" ).append('<input type="text" value="'+texto+'" disabled/>');
                    });
        }
    });
</script>
```

para funcionar basta retornar o texto na pagina resposta.php, o seu caso é bem genérico, não sei se você esta usando algum tipo de drive para acessar o banco ou alguma abstração do código, de qualquer forma, acredito que isso possa te dar uma ideia de como implementar seu código em qualquer outra situação !

```
<?php
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "userTeste";   
$password = "passTeste"
$con = mysql_connect("$hostname", "$username", "$password") or die(mysql_error());

$query = "SELECT * FROM sua_tabela";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc ($result){
    echo $row;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa ser um tanto mais claro.

Veja bem: O input que você deseja exibir ao "checar" um determinado checkbox já está preenchido com as informações advindas do Banco de Dados?

Se sim, então:

```
$(document).on('change', '#checkBoxTeste', function(){
  if(this.checked){
    $('#inputTeste').slideDown().prop('disabled',true);
  }else{
    $('#inputTeste').slideUp();
  }
}
```

Agora se os dados do input precisar ser carregados após "checado" o checkbox, então precisarás fazer uso do `$.ajax()` dentro da condição `if` quando ela retornar `true`.

Caso ainda prefira, adicione o atributo disabled inline no input text, evitando assim um comando ( `.prop()` ) do jQuery e enxugando ainda mais o seu código.

Esta é uma ideia e existem outras mais como por exemplo usar `$('#inputTeste').css('display', 'block')` para exibir e `$('#inputTeste').css('display', 'none')` para ocultar o input text no contexto em que você informou.

Comment: Na minha dúvida eu relato que vem informações do banco de dados. Não sei se você prestou atenção. Contudo, vou analisar sua questão!

Comment: Desculpe, minha pergunta tinha o intuito de saber se a vinda das informações eram antes, quando a página fosse carregada por exemplo, ou depois/enquanto exibido o input text (neste caso, via `$.ajax` por exemplo). Isso não ficou claro na sua pergunta. Questionei porque isso mudaria a forma com qual você obteria uma resposta mais direta.

Answer (score 0):

Não mando bem em JavaScript nem Ajax ainda porque odeio a sintaxe deles, mas de PHP eu manjo.

> Então segue o Fluxo :D

1º Encontre entre os nossos amigos Javeiros nerds aii uma boa solução em Ajax para mostrar ou esconder o campo.

2º Para trazer o resultado do MySQL Venha comigo "Jeday"

Conecta ao db **(ConfigDB.php)**

```
 // definições de host, database, usuário e senha
 $host = "localhost";
 $db   = "seuDb";
 $user = "user";
 $pass = "senha";
 // conecta ao banco de dados (Eu Já uso Mysqli Cowboy) :D
 $con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
 ?>
```

Agora Carrega tudo em uma Array (Ou vetor já que estamos numa comunidade Br Hu3) **(ListaDados.php)**

```
    <?php
    $Checkbox_id = "aqui o id do registro que cê quer puxar";
    //Inclui as credenciais de Conexão
    include ("configBD.php");
    //Define a query
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `tabela` WHERE ID `registro_id` = '$Checkbox_id' ";

    // executa a query
    $dados = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));

   // transforma os dados em um array
   // Essa Linha Chama o primeiro registro, então na consulta só mostra do segundo valor em diante
   $linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dados);


   /* Essa Linha Reseta as Chamadas para poder exibir do primeiro em Diante Desculpa o POG aí */
  mysqli_data_seek($dados, '0');

  // calcula quantos dados retornaram 
  $total = mysqli_num_rows($dados);

  ?>
```

Okay Manolo, tuu já tens a faca e o queijo na mão, todos os dados do seu BD já estão bonitinhos dentro da array `$linha[];` pra mostrar é só dar um `echo` com o campo do banco de dados que você quer exibir Ex:

```
    <?=$linha['checkbox_id']?>
    // onde checkbox_id é o nome do campo na tabela mysql
    //vai mostrar o id cadastrado no banco de dados, e assim por diante
```

Agora vamos mostrar no HTML (index.php)

```
    <?php require("listaDados.php");?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="pt-br">
    <body>
    <?php
      // se o número de resultados for maior que zero, mostra os dados
      while($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($dados)) { 
        ?>
      <input type="checkbox" id="<?=$linha['checkbox_id']?>" value="<?=$linha['checkbox_valor']?>" selected="<?=$linha['checkbox_selecionado']?>" >
    <?php } ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

> Se deu Ruim Comenta aê que eu vou ali pegar um Café ;)

Answer (score 0):

Como você não descreveu a forma como será enviado o parâmetro ao banco de dados deixei um exemplo de como eu faria para realizar a exibição dos dados do input desabilitado. Como exemplo exibi o mesmo valor do input. 
Segue abaixo o modelo:

```js
    $('input[type=text]').hide();
    $('input').change(function(){
        if(this.checked){
          var valor = $(this).val();
          
          $(this).next().val(valor).show();         
        }else{
            
            $(this).next().val('').hide();
        }

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        Tipo 1<input type="checkbox" name="tipo1" id="" value="tipo1"><input type="text" disabled></input><br>
        Tipo 2<input type="checkbox" name="tipo2" id="" value="tipo2"><input type="text" disabled></input><br>
```

Exemplo no [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adrianoavelino/jhyp3gfx/).

Answer (score 0):

Cara estou tentando fazer isso tambem. mas eu quero recuperar dados de 2 tabelas.
por exemplo eu tenho uma tabela genero `ação, terro, ficção...` e outra
`filme_genero`. Ou seja elas são relacionadas e quero mostrar genero na tela, e tambem mostrar checado aqueles que fazem parte desse genero

qual seria o cod melhor para implementar.?
veja meu cod.

```
for($i=0; $i < $numTotal_g; $i++){
    $result_fg = $filmeg->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $id_fg = $result_fg['id_genero'];
    $result_g['id'];
    $result_g['nome'];
?>  
<li><input  type="checkbox" name="check[]" id="check[]" 

<?php

    if($result_fg['id_genero'] == $result_g['id']){
        echo  'checked';
    } 
?>
```

Mas do jeito que está ai, so aparece o primeiro de genero e fica repetindo,